# JPQL Quesry in ManyToMany relation using JoinTable

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have three entities bellow. I want to get a List of RULE by DEP id using JPA

RULE----------OneToMany---------->EMP------------ManyToMany------------>DEP  .

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "EMP")
    public class Emp implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;


        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "emp")
        private List<Rule> rules;

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "rule_ref_sub_category_ref", joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "DEP_REF_ID") })
        private List<Dep> Deps;
    }


     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name="DEP")
    public class Dep implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name="LABEL")
        private String label;

        private int mandatory;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy="Deps")
        private List<Emp> emps;

    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name="RULES")
    public class Rule implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="EMP_REF_ID")
        private Emp emp;
    }
```

Can someOne please guide me with a sample JPQL request to resovle this.

Comment: Standing by entities you posted it's actually
RULE----------ManyToOne---------->EMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a pretty straightforward query

```
select r from rule r
join r.emp emp
join emp.Deps dep
where dep.id = :depId
```

read a bit of the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms) to understand the possible form of join syntax